# wp7 pass html data in to web browser controll

Tags: string, windows-phone-7

I want to pass string variable in `webBrowser.NavigateToString(varivale);`
In this varible i stored a html source.
How can i pass variable in this method?

my code is

```
string varible=<body>..<p>some text</p>..</body>;
webBrowser1.NavigateToString(variable);
```

see my actual code:

```
JObject cityblog1 = (JObject)cityblog[0];
        string cityimg = (string)cityblog1["CityImage"];
        string  citydetail = (string)cityblog1["CityDetail"];
        //var  = (string)cityblog1["CityDetail"];

        City_Blog cb = new City_Blog();
        cb.CityImage = cityimg;
        cb.CityDetail = citydetail;
        lstcityblogdetail.Add(cb);
        setimg();


        webBrowser1.NavigateToString(ConvertExtendedASCII(citydetail));            

    }
    private static string ConvertExtendedASCII(string HTML)
    {
        string retVal = "";
        char[] s = HTML.ToCharArray();

        foreach (char c in s)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(c) > 127)
                retVal += "&#" + Convert.ToInt32(c) + ";";
            else
                retVal += c;
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

**The problem:**

When I run application my output is all the tag of controller like `&nbsp` or etc.But I dont want that.

Comment: @lgor:when i run application my out put is all the tag of controller like &nbsp or etc.But i dont want that

Comment: @Olag:i want dipaly my html content in web controler and my html code is stored in one string.now i want to put this code in to navigationTostring method

Comment: @Mansinh add this info (about broken tags) into you question, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you do it in a right way.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/16/displaying-html-content-in-windows-phone-7.aspx

the only problem that I can see in your code - you declare a `varible` in a wrong way:

```
string varible = "<body>..<p>some text</p>..</body>";
```

You have forgot quotes.

**upd**
try this one:

```
var htmlCode = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(citydetail);
webBrowser1..NavigateToString(ConvertExtendedASCII(htmlCode ));
```

Comment: Sizilov:actully i not forgot quotes but my string is came form web service

Comment: one more idea in update. Also, could you show us a piece of citydetail string before and after ConvertExtendedASCII method?

Comment: :<body style="text-align:justify"><p> <a href="46" style="color: red">Test</a></p> <p> &amp;#39;</p> </body>                                                              both are same before and after convert